# Tensorflow- restoring a model consumes all the memory on subsequent iterations

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, artificial-intelligence

I am trying to train a simple neural network in which I need to save my model, load new data set and restore the model. This work save-restore process consumes all of my memory after 3 or 4 iterations. Here is the relevant part of my code. The runsess() function is iterated many times in a loop.

```
num_steps = 50

with tf.Session(graph=graph) as session:
   tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
   print("Initialized")
   for step in range(num_steps):
     offset = (step * batch_size) % (train_labels.shape[0] - batch_size)
     batch_data = train_dataset[offset:(offset + batch_size)]
     batch_labels = train_labels[offset:(offset + batch_size)]
     feed_dict = {tf_train_dataset : batch_data, tf_train_labels : batch_labels}

     _, l, predictions = session.run([optimizer, loss, train_prediction], feed_dict=feed_dict)

     if (step % 10 == 0):
       print("Minibatch loss at step %d: %f" % (step, l))
       print("Minibatch accuracy: %.1f%%" % accuracy(predictions, batch_labels))
       print("Validation accuracy: %.1f%%\n" % accuracy(valid_prediction.eval(), valid_labels))


   print("Test accuracy: %.1f%%" % accuracy(test_prediction.eval(), test_labels))

   # Saving the session
   saver = tf.train.Saver()
   save_path = "./checkpoints/model.ckpt"
   saver.save(session, save_path)
   print("Model saved in file: %s" % save_path)
   session.close()


def runsess(graph,num_steps):
  with tf.Session(graph=graph) as session:
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('./checkpoints/model.ckpt.meta')
    saver.restore(session,tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./checkpoints/'))
    tf.global_variables_initializer()
    print("Initialized")
    tf.get_default_graph()
    for step in range(num_steps):
      offset = (step * batch_size) % (train_labels.shape[0] - batch_size)
      batch_data = train_dataset[offset:(offset + batch_size)]
      batch_labels = train_labels[offset:(offset + batch_size)]
      feed_dict = {tf_train_dataset : batch_data, tf_train_labels : batch_labels}

      _, l, predictions = session.run([optimizer, loss, train_prediction], feed_dict=feed_dict)
      if (step % 10 == 0):
        print("Minibatch loss at step %d: %f" % (step, l))
        print("Minibatch accuracy: %.1f%%" % accuracy(predictions, batch_labels))
        print("Validation accuracy: %.1f%%\n" % accuracy(valid_prediction.eval(), valid_labels))
    print("Test accuracy: %.1f%%" % accuracy(test_prediction.eval(), test_labels))

    saver.save(session, save_path)
    session.close()
```

It seems I am doing a mistake while saving the model in runsess() but I do not understand where and how. How do I solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you call functions which **create new ops in your graph**, thus leading to memory consumption.

First of all you should have **one** saver, you cannot create it in the loop, each saver will create assign ops.

```
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('./checkpoints/model.ckpt.meta')
saver.restore(session,tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./checkpoints/'))
```

Second of all, global_variables_initializer creates an op (actually **a lot** of ops) too, yet you call it and do not even store the result. Despite the name, this function **does not** initialise variables - it creates an op to do so - just remove it in your case.

```
tf.global_variables_initializer()
```

The easiest way to understand which functions do modify your graph or do not is to **always finalize your graph** once you are done constructing it. This way every time you call a function which creates new ops - you will get an exception telling you so, and you will be able to debug it.

```
tf.get_default_graph().finalize()
```

Comment: This was extremely helpful. Finalizing the graph shows that with every iteration it is appending the same graph to the previous graph. Making the graph with Tensorboard too shows this. Although, removing the save function from the loop causes it to loose all the progress made during the previous session. I am not clear how to resolve this.